# Why is approving edits a higher privilege than actually editing?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, privileges

I saw a question that was in dire need of formatting and saw that another user had submitted a pending edit. Although I could view the diff, I didn't see a way to accept the edit. (Please do point out if I overlooked something.)

Users who are trusted enough to write their own edits should also able to exercise good judgement in approving others'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All users who have greater than 2,000 rep on a site gain full editing rights. Along with these rights comes the ability to approve or reject edits. I don't have a screenshot available right now, but please look carefully at the bottom of the page for the buttons.

However, note that Stack Overflow (and *only* Stack Overflow), for various reasons, requires 2 users with full editing rights to approve or reject edits.